# WPF: Mystery with RichTextBox and KeyDown Event

Tags: wpf, menu, focus, richtextbox

Before I explain, I will present code, because it is the best way to express the question in this case. a simple WPF window, his base node contains this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Menu>
        <TextBox x:Name"A" Width="200" />
    </Menu>

    <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0">--richTB--</TextBlock>

    <RichTextBox x:Name"B" />

    <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0">--simpleTB--</TextBlock>

    <TextBox x:Name"C" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now, if the focus is in the buttom `TextBox` (C), and by a Mouse-click I move focus to the top `TextBox` within menu (A), and then I hit `Enter` key, the focus returns to the  buttom `TextBox` (C). This behavior of the `MenuItem` that `Enter` key "selects" and returns the focus. so far everything is normal.

But, if i focus `RichTextBox` (B), and then I go through the  top `TextBox` (A), when I tap Return cursor will remain in the box.

I made another little test, and I listening the `PreviewKeyDown` & `KeyDown` events for the `TextBox` within menu (A). So:

```
<Menu>
    <TextBox Width="200" KeyDown="TB_KeyDown" PreviewKeyDown="TB_PreviewKeyDown" />
</Menu>
```

What I discovered? The last scenario in which the focus was first `RichTextBox` (B) and then in `TextBox` within menu (A), there are no listening to the `KeyDown` for `Enter` key!

Comment: Interesting... Have you tried setting `AcceptsReturn="True"` in the `RichTextBox` (or the `TextBox`, since you're at it)? Or subscribing to the `RichTextBox`'s events... Since it seems like it is effectively stealing them from the focused TextBox.

Comment: @almulo ywe i tryed. `AcceptRetun` dosent effect. the events of `RichTextBox` dosent fired when the cursor focused in `TextBox`.

Comment: That is extra-weird :P I'll try to reproduce it and see what I can find.